# change listviewitem tooltip to balloon

Tags: c#, listview, tooltip, balloon

is there a simple way to set the tooltip property of a listview item to be a balloon? Typically all i would do is:

```
Tooltip tt = new Tooltip("This is a tooltip");
tt.isBalloon = true;
```

but how do i do this for a listview item

Answer (score 1):

You can manually show `ToolTip` when mouse is over certain item

check this [article](http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/faqs/?id=listviewitemtooltips&lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to change the tooltip on a ListView. See [this blog](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog2.html) for a detailed explanation of why.

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) -- an open source wrapper around a standard WinForms ListView -- does a reasonable amount of work for you so that you can show enhanced tool tips with minimal effort on your part.

[image: Tooltip on an ObjectListView]

Even if you don't want to use ObjectListView, you can still look at the code to see how it is done (admittedly, in the case of tool tips, there was a lot of work done and it would be tricky to extract that work into another project)