# How can I modify the appearance of ListViewItem.ToolTIp Property?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, tooltip

I recently asked how to get a toolTip to show up on a ListViewItem ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117362/can-i-get-a-mouseover-event-to-show-small-dialog-box-for-an-item-in-the-listview)).  My question is, does anyone know how I would control the colour, size or font of this [ListViewItem.ToolTipText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tooltiptext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)??

I have tried a few suggestions about "custom tool tips" but they never seem to actually show a tool tip ([like this example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/bdd35f21-1d51-4cc9-812e-d30cc16032d7/))  In this example, debugging shows that it definitely goes into the mouseover method but never seems to present a tool box - a constant resetting by the form perhaps?

It doesn't seem to have any properties to change but I know that there always seems to be a way around things!

Comment: I researched a bit because that I knew you could not change the Style of a toolTip. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159426/change-listviewitem-tooltip-to-balloon and inside http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog2.html I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I will follow this and see where it goes.